# Наследование в React или как реализовать банальный функционал?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять как это сделать в React?

Есть два десятка компонентов. У всех них должны быть свойства `hidden/visible` `enable/disable`, также все компоненты должны иметь модификации `default/error/warning` с разным внешним видом.

Можно ли реализовать это без костылей?

Пока на ум приходит следующее:

- Написать компонент `Container` в вышеперечисленными возможностями и обернуть им остальные компоненты, но это костыль.
- Написать метод `createClassName`, возвращающий строку с необходимыми css-классами. Во всех остальных компонентах в методе `render` писать `</MyComponent className={this.createClassName()} />`, но это тоже костыль.

Может есть более адекватные варианты?

Comment: Container вроде бы не самый плохой вариант:)

Comment: Что-то не очень хочется переписывать двадцать компонентов :)

Comment: мимо реката проходил, но всё же: функциональный стиль или на классах? привели бы пример ... если на классах - `extend BaseCl` если на функциях, мм ?прототипы или обёртывания

Comment: Не совсем пример, на все-таки [https://codesandbox.io/s/34ymrv2jy6](https://codesandbox.io/s/34ymrv2jy6).